# How to transliterate Devanagari into Brahmi (mainly, diacritics)

Tags: sanskrit, transliteration, devanagari

I have been messing around with converting a large Devanagari Sanskrit text to Brahmi using a simple mapping function. There is also [this table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brahmic_scripts) showing how most of the characters map. I found one that doesn't though, the [`ऽ`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Avagraha). Right now I'm just mapping it to अ, but please correct me if I'm wrong.

What I'm wondering about though is how to convert Sanskrit Devanagari text to Brahmi. Can I just strip the diacritics and call it a day? Or do I need to be more careful and look at *(unicode) character combinations* (like letter + diacritic) to map to a single (or perhaps multiple) Brahmi letter(s)? How do I convert Sanskrit Devanagari to Brahmi?

Right now I have this (the mapping is just what I wanted to show in case it's relevant):

```
var MAP = {
  "ऽ": "\u{11005}",
  "ॠ": "",
  "\u0905": "\u{11005}",
  "\u0906": "\u{11006}",
  "\u0907": "\u{11007}",
  "\u0908": "\u{11008}",
  "\u0909": "\u{11009}",
  "\u090A": "\u{1100A}",
  "\u090B": "\u{1100B}",
  "\u090C": "\u{1100D}",
  "\u090F": "\u{1100F}",
  "\u0910": "\u{11010}",
  "\u0913": "\u{11011}",
  "\u0914": "\u{11012}",
  "\u0915": "\u{11013}",
  "\u0916": "\u{11014}",
  "\u0917": "\u{11015}",
  "\u0918": "\u{11016}",
  "\u0919": "\u{11017}",
  "\u091A": "\u{11018}",
  "\u091B": "\u{11019}",
  "\u091C": "\u{1101A}",
  "\u091D": "\u{1101B}",
  "\u091E": "\u{1101C}",
  "\u091F": "\u{1101D}",
  "\u0920": "\u{1101E}",
  "\u0921": "\u{1101F}",
  "\u0922": "\u{11020}",
  "\u0923": "\u{11021}",
  "\u0924": "\u{11022}",
  "\u0925": "\u{11023}",
  "\u0926": "\u{11024}",
  "\u0927": "\u{11025}",
  "\u0928": "\u{11026}",
  "\u092A": "\u{11027}",
  "\u092B": "\u{11028}",
  "\u092C": "\u{11029}",
  "\u092D": "\u{1102A}",
  "\u092E": "\u{1102B}",
  "\u092F": "\u{1102C}",
  "\u0930": "\u{1102D}",
  "\u0932": "\u{1102E}",
  "\u0933": "\u{11034}",
  "\u0935": "\u{1102F}",
  "\u0936": "\u{11030}",
  "\u0937": "\u{11031}",
  "\u0938": "\u{11032}",
  "\u0939": "\u{11033}",
  "\u093E": "\u{11038}",
  "\u093F": "\u{1103A}",
  "\u0940": "\u{1103B}",
  "\u0941": "\u{1103C}",
  "\u0942": "\u{1103D}",
  "\u0943": "\u{1103E}",
  "\u0944": "\u{1103F}",
  "\u0962": "\u{11040}",
  "\u0963": "\u{11041}",
  "\u0947": "\u{11042}",
  "\u0948": "\u{11043}",
  "\u094B": "\u{11044}",
  "\u094C": "\u{11045}",
  "\u094D": "\u{11046}",
  "\u0964": "\u{11047}",
  "\u0965": "\u{11048}",
  "\u0966": "\u{11066}",
  "\u0967": "\u{11067}",
  "\u0968": "\u{11068}",
  "\u0969": "\u{11069}",
  "\u096A": "\u{1106A}",
  "\u096B": "\u{1106B}",
  "\u096C": "\u{1106C}",
  "\u096D": "\u{1106D}",
  "\u096E": "\u{1106E}",
  "\u096F": "\u{1106F}"
}

var combining = [
  '\u0900',
  '\u0901',
  '\u0902',
  '\u0903',
  '\u093a',
  '\u093b',
  '\u093c',
  '\u093e',
  '\u093f',
  '\u0940',
  '\u0941',
  '\u0942',
  '\u0943',
  '\u0944',
  '\u0945',
  '\u0946',
  '\u0947',
  '\u0948',
  '\u0949',
  '\u094a',
  '\u094b',
  '\u094c',
  '\u094d',
  '\u094e',
  '\u094f',
  '\u0955',
  '\u0956',
  '\u0957',
  '\uA8E0',
  '\uA8E1',
  '\uA8E2',
  '\uA8E3',
  '\uA8E4',
  '\uA8E5',
  '\uA8E6',
  '\uA8E7',
  '\uA8E8',
  '\uA8E9',
  '\uA8Ea',
  '\uA8Eb',
  '\uA8Ec',
  '\uA8Ed',
  '\uA8Ee',
  '\uA8Ef',
  '\uA8f0',
  '\uA8f1',
  '\u1CD1',
  '\u1CD4',
  '\u1CDb',
  '\u1CDe',
  '\u1CDf',
  '\u1Ce2',
  '\u1Ce3',
  '\u1Ce4',
  '\u1Ce5',
  '\u1Ce6',
  '\u1Ce7',
  '\u1Ce8',
  '\u1CF7',
]

var chars = []
for (var char of text) {
  char = char
    .replace(/\s+/g, '')
    .replace(/[\{\};\:\.,\"\'\(\)।॥\[\]]/g, '')
  if (!char) continue // ignore whitespace
  if (combining.includes(char)) continue // ignore diacritics?
  chars.push(MAP[char]) // brahmi character
}
```

What could I be doing better?

Note, I am wondering less about the code/technical aspects, and more about the linguistic aspect of orthography to orthography.

Comment: As a general rule, diacritics are there for a reason. Just because English doesn't use combining diacritics doesn't mean they're not important in other languages!

Comment: Original Quran didn't use them.

Comment: Can you paint me a general picture of an algorithm pretty please .

Comment: I can't read Brahmi, but I have never seen the ऽ in the current writing of any of the Indic scripts I *can* read. Stripping diacritics from Sanskrit Devanagari will render it gibberish. Why don't you do a 1:1 map between the diacritics too?

Comment: I should have explained why removing diacritics is a bad idea: these diacritics indicate vowels, and removing them has the effect of replacing all vowels with the default, ǝ.

Comment: Unless I'm very mistaken, original Brahmi was also an abugida like Devanagari is, so if by "diacritics" you mean the vowels, then removing them would make it gibberish in *either* script.

Comment: This question is 10 months old so I don't know if you're still interested, but you can take a look at https://aksharamukha.appspot.com/converter which is the best of the lot. Basically you can mostly do a one-to-one mapping of both the consonants and vowels (including vowel signs which are combining characters, what you called “diacritics” but cannot possibly be dropped): use the names in the code charts ([Brahmi](https://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/U11000.pdf#page=3), [Devanagari](https://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/U0900.pdf#page=3)). If you're interested I'll write a more elaborate answer.